# Force flexbox columns to be equal on a `flex-direction: column` container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I force the widths of the Flexbox columns to be equal (the max of all the columns) on a `flex-direction: column` container? I don't want to explictly set the widths using `flex-basis`, `width` properties.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/suthanbala/1u9gtqkm/6/

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.column{
  border: 1px red dashed;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Small Content
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Medium Content Medium Content
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Large Content Large Content Large Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't really need flexbox, inline-block or display:table on the container will do the job

Comment: Achieving the equal width of the columns with max-width of the columns won't be possible with the `display: inline-block` right? Not sure of the `display: table`, haven't used it much

Comment: it's possible, in the  accepted answer replace inline-flex with inline-block or table and you will get the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all columns to be as wide as the largest, you can make the container `inline-flex` and remove the align items:

```css
.row{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column{
  border: 1px red dashed;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    Small Content
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Medium Content Medium Content
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    Large Content Large Content Large Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove align-items: flex-start;

Comment: That would cause the columns to cover the entire width of the container.. I just want the columns' widths to be equalized to the max width of any columns